# What is the definition of "representative $a$ of $\bar b$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, definition

I was reading S.Lang's Algebra and it says *"Let $ \bar b$ be an element of $A/A_1'$ of period $p^r$, Then there exists a
representative $a$ of $\bar b$ in $A$ which also has period $p^r$"* in lemma $8.3$.

I couldn't find the definition of the term *"representative $a$ of $\bar b$"*.

ps. I am sorry if my English is bad, I'm not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, a **quotient** of a set is a partition into subsets, called congruence classes.

An element of the quotient set is one of these congruence classes. A **representative** of a class is simply an element of that class.

E.g. $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=\{\bar 0= \text{set of even integers}, \bar 1= \text{set of odd integers}\}$, and a representative of $\bar 0$ is simply any even integer.